# How to update a nested attributes using select_tag instead of fields_for

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

So I have a 2 Model that has a relationship of `belongs_to` and `has_many`, `PermissionGroup` and `Permission` respectively. On my `view/permission_groups/edit.html.erb`. I have a `button` that will add a `<tr></tr>` row with a select tag, this will add new  `permissions` under the current `permission_group`. I also have a `@authorizable_models` that has an array of strings

The problems that I got are:

1. if `permissions` is empty why cant I use `fields for` to render a collection_select. I commented it out because I cant use it. its not showing in the DOM

2.When I add a multiple `row` for permissions how can I update this?. Is there a bulk update?

3. if I cant do a bulk update is it good idea to loop through each permissions then create them on the my permission_group_controller?
4. Is there a way to update a nested attributes using select_tag instead of fields_for?

```
<button id="add_new_permission">Add New Permission</button>

<%= form_for [:admin, @permission_group] do |f| %>

        <% if @permission_group.permissions.empty? %>
          <%#= f.fields_for :permissions do |pm| %>
            <tr id="none" data-hook="product_line_item_option_type_conditions_none">
              <td>
                <%= select_tag :name, options_for_select(@authorizable_models), class: "select2" %>
                <%#= pm.collection_select(:name, @authorizable_models, :to_s, :to_s, { include_blank: false}, { class: 'form-control'} ) %>
              </td>
              <td class="actions text-center"></td>
              <td class="actions actions-1 text-center"><%#= link_to_icon_remove_fields pm %></td>
            </tr>
          <%#end%>
        <% else %>
          <%= f.fields_for :permissions do |pm| %>
            <tr>
              <td class="permission_group_permission_name">
                <%#= pm.collection_select :name, class: "form-control"%>
                <%= pm.collection_select(:name, @authorizable_models, :to_s, :to_s, { include_blank: false}, { class: 'form-control'} ) %>
              </td>
              <td class="permission_group_permission_action">
                <%= pm.text_field :action, class: "form-control"%>
              </td>
              <td class="actions actions-1 text-center"><%= link_to_icon_remove_fields pm %></td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
        <%end%>


<% end %>
```